# Seeking US public school serving area boundaries

Tags: usa, geospatial, us-census, education, kml

I am trying to get the serving area for public schools in US. I can get a lot of KML from the census website at https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-kml.html

However, it only has school district kml boundaries, but not each individual school.

Is there any way that I can get the boundaries for each US public school?

Comment: I too have been curious about these boundaries. Not even AOG's/COG's carry this information. For whatever reason, it seems to be a closely-guarded secret for K-12 institutions.

Comment: By the way, there is a resource for the 2013 to 2014 School Year from NCES, known as the [School Attendance Boundary Survey (SABS)](https://nces.ed.gov/programs/sabs/). It is a valiant effort put forth by them, and I wish it would continue. However, in my capacity, I have already seen school boundaries that do not align well between SABS and a school's own attendance boundary.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way...but its not a silver bullet; very time intensive and may require learning new skillsets.
You can search through data portals and collect them along the way:

[Here's a search on data.gov for "School Boundaries"](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=School+Boundaries&sort=score+desc%2C+name+asc&as_sfid=AAAAAAWMe5zr_5zOdC8NduHzMcyijUCNO79gkcjBKkuTe282U50rXR0oa7i4tEMNJi97IB1IiayKxpcju4R5DGCRNH9lCCdMPXF0QariNp17cB91ar8WyIZcfNkW3mVF7oXMAhU%3D&as_fid=e1318ab37cf0359ff21fb15568a32b276046741d), and 
 [here is a search on ESRI's ArcGIS site for "School Boundaries"](http://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?t=content&q=School%20Boundaries&start=1&sortOrder=desc&sortField=relevance).

But those are being optimistic; to @Kotebiya's point in the question comments, the data changes annually.
To that point, and the general search question, you're best bet is to go to each district's website and find the GIS data there.